# Singleton NServiceBus Saga

Tags: c#, nservicebus, saga

What would be the correct way to have all the messages processed by a single saga?

I don't think I can not specify some `message-to-saga` correlation.  Can I?  I believe it would result in a "saga not found" error.

A naive way would be to have some constant ID in the saga, but that seems wrong.

```
class SomePolicy :
    Saga<SomePolicy.State>,
    IAmStartedByMessages<SomeEvent>
{
    internal class State : ContainSagaData
    {
        public int Id { get { return 1; } }
    }

    protected override void ConfigureHowToFindSaga(SagaPropertyMapper<State> mapper)
    {
        mapper
            .ConfigureMapping<SomeEvent>(message => message.MagicConstant)
            .ToSaga(saga => saga.Id);
    }

    public void Handle(SomeEvent message)
    {
        // Modify the saga state here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: This looks correct (didn't run the code), what is your issue?

What are you trying to do?

Comment: @TomRedfern let's say I want to aggregate some global information, such as how many times certain events occur in the system, I could use a singleton saga to receive all these events, increment some counter and perform an action when the counter reaches a certain threshold.

Comment: @SeanFarmar I'm really just looking for some sort of best practice, if there is any.  It feels wrong that I have to correlate things that way, given that correlation should always give the same result.

Comment: But why do you need the correlation to give the same result? What's the functional reasoning behind this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you can explain your business use case it will help to suggest a good solution, at the moment I find it difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve... There is no one solution for all scenarios, and your question sounds like a special case (to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than override `ConfigureHowToFindSaga` you can supply an implementation of `IFindSagas<T>.Using<M>` which is used to find a saga of type T from a message of type M. Then just have it always return the same instance.

See [Complex Saga Finding Logic](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/saga-finding) for more details and some samples.